# rails 5 bootstrap 4 stylesheet for print background color

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, printing, ruby-on-rails-5

good morning,

well I have rails 5 bootstrap 4 app which try when is page printer to assign background colors.

I started with

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application-print', media: 'print' %>
```

and created 
application-print.css
 with this content

```
   .table-plus {
    background-color: #d0ffd0 !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;

  }
  .table-minus {
    background-color: #ff4040 !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;
  }
```

but when I click on stylesheet for print then it reports me as unknown route  can somebody give me advice on how to properly add printer sheets ?

Thanks

T.Krmela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**These Steps Should Help You**

Simply link style sheet to your layout

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/application-print.css" media="print">
```

**OR**

You may have forgot to precompile your application-print.css file when your server starts so in your `/config/initializers/assets.rb` file write following lines.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(application-print.css)
```

You should put your file in `app/assets/stylesheets` folder first.

Now you can use:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application-print', media: 'print' %>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No route matches [GET] "/assets/stylesheets/application-print.css" when i am test if is loads with <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/stylesheets/application-print.css" media="print">

Comment: to use first method your assets should be in public folder. In second method put assets in app/assets folder.